# wix: uninstall of application which uses a Service requires restart?

Tags: windows, installation, wix

We developed an installer using Wix, and after uninstalling our app it suggests that we reboot the computer.  It seems due to our app having installed a Windows Service.

Is there any way we can avoid reboot, maybe if we have some code which stops the service, unregisters it, etc?

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the `ServiceControl` element:

```
<ServiceControl Id="ServiceController" Start="install" Stop="both" Remove="uninstall" Name="{NameOfYourService}"/>
```

This will:

- start the service after installing
- stop the service when both installing and uninstalling
- remove the service when uninstalling

The docs are [here](http://wix.sourceforge.net/manual-wix3/wix_xsd_servicecontrol.htm) if you need them.

Comment: Will give it a try next week... I just hate forced reboots! :)